# How to prevent reload of page in Richfaces on action/event?

Tags: events, jsf-2, richfaces, reload

I am using JSF2.0 and RichFaces 4.0.1 Final. I want to prevent the reload of page on occurence of event.

My use case is: There is a Command button with hidden style. I need to invoke the event attached to it in certain case from Javascript.

Problem: Though I am able to invoke the hidden button, the issue is, the moment it gets invoked, the page is getting reloaded. I want to prevent this reload.

Comment: please post your code. 
do you use h:commandButton or a:commandButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use ajax:

```
<h:commandButton id="foo" action="#{bean.foo}" styleClass="hide">
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandButton>
```

Or, since you're already using RichFaces:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="foo" action="#{bean.foo}" styleClass="hide" />
```